# Insert date using a calendar

Tags: calendar

How can I do the following in emacs:

Suppose the cursor is at position A in my text. Then

- open a calendar
- chooses the date by clicking with the mouse or navigating with the keyboard
- insert the choosen date at A

The solution should work in all modes and the date format should be configurable.

Comment: while I understand what you mean :), what is the current point? Because when you choose a date in a calendar, current point is the place in your calendar.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to make it clearer, see my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```el
(defun calendar-insert-date ()
  "Capture the date at point, exit the Calendar, insert the date."
  (interactive)
  (seq-let (month day year) (save-match-data (calendar-cursor-to-date))
    (calendar-exit)
    (insert (format "%d-%02d-%02d" year month day))))

(define-key calendar-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'calendar-insert-date)
```

To insert a date at point, use

1. `M-x calendar`
2. Adjust the date as needed
3. `RET`

---

By the way, I am not familiar with the Calendar at all, thus maybe there is a better way I don't know.

Comment: Is it also possible to get the date numbers with leading zeros, for example 2018-03-07 instead of 2018-3-7?

Comment: @student Yes, I've update the answer to use that format. Beside `format`, another option is `format-time-string`, though you have to use `encode-time` to convert year/month/day into a time value..

Comment: Defining keys for `calendar-mode-map` appears to only work once the calendar had been opened before during the current Emacs session.  Otherwise, the `define-key` statement will fail (e.g. if above code would go into your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file).  If placed inside the `defun`, it will work as the calendar is open by the time this statement is called.

Answer (score 2):

```lisp
(defun org-insert-date ()
"Insert a date at point using `org-read-date' with its optional argument
of TO-TIME so that the user can customize the date format more easily."
(interactive)
  (require 'org)
  (let ((time (org-read-date nil 'to-time nil "Date:  ")))
    (insert (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d" time))))
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know -- there is no built in function to do what you want.

But you can try to do it yourself.

1. there is [How to retrieve the date under the cursor in emacs calendar as the format day.month.year like 15.07.2018](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41978/how-to-retrieve-the-date-under-the-cursor-in-emacs-calendar-as-the-format-day-mo/41987)

   Using the solution from the answer you will be able to open calendar, press `M-w` on a date, close calendar and paste the date with `C-y`. (And I usually do this)
2. Now if it is not enough, you can learn some emacs lisp and try to automate the process from the 1.