# Can I copy a date from M-x calendar into kill ring or buffer

Tags: copy-paste, calendar

I would like to be able to run M-x calendar, navigate to a date, press some keystroke which would do one of the following:

1. place the selected date onto the kill ring

or

2. close the calendar and insert the selected date into my current buffer.

Is there any built-in functionality for this?

Comment: Similar question
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/42529/insert-date-using-a-calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org-read-date` uses the function `calendar` from the `calendar.el` library.  It is not necessary to be in an `org-mode` buffer to use `org-read-date`; i.e, the function `org-insert-copy-date` should work in just about any buffer that is read-write.  The nifty thing about `org-read-date` is that you can use the mouse to select a date and exit, or use the minibuffer to select a date (which has some pretty overlays).

```lisp
(defun org-insert-copy-date ()
"Insert a date at point using `org-read-date' with its optional argument
of TO-TIME so that the user can customize the date format more easily.
Also, copy the time-string to the `kill-ring'."
(interactive)
  (require 'org)
  (let* ((time (org-read-date nil 'to-time nil "Date:  "))
         (time-string (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d" time)))
    (kill-new time-string)
    (insert time-string)))
```